# Android: How do I keep DrawerLayout from passing touch events to the underlying view

Tags: android, android-support-library, drawerlayout

I am using the Support library's `DrawerLayout` in my app. I noticed that, when I click on an empty area in my Drawer view, the underlying View (containing a `ListView`) receives the Touch event and reacts to it.

The `onInterceptTouchEvent` method of the `DrawerLayout` looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

    // "|" used deliberately here; both methods should be invoked.
    final boolean interceptForDrag = mLeftDragger.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ev) |
            mRightDragger.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

    boolean interceptForTap = false;

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();
            mInitialMotionX = x;
            mInitialMotionY = y;
            if (mScrimOpacity > 0 &&
                    isContentView(mLeftDragger.findTopChildUnder((int) x, (int) y))) {
                interceptForTap = true;
            }
            mDisallowInterceptRequested = false;
            mChildrenCanceledTouch = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            // If we cross the touch slop, don't perform the delayed peek for an edge touch.
            if (mLeftDragger.checkTouchSlop(ViewDragHelper.DIRECTION_ALL)) {
                mLeftCallback.removeCallbacks();
                mRightCallback.removeCallbacks();
            }
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            closeDrawers(true);
            mDisallowInterceptRequested = false;
            mChildrenCanceledTouch = false;
        }
    }

    return interceptForDrag || interceptForTap || hasPeekingDrawer() || mChildrenCanceledTouch;
}
```

My view with the `DrawerLayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sidebar_container"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What can I do, (if possible without extending the `DrawerLayout` class) to prevent this behaviour? As long as the drawer is open, I want no click events to reach the background view.

Comment: When the drawer is about to be opened add a simple `View` on top of your app's current content which has a `OnTouchListener` set on it to return `true`(meaning it will eat all the touch events).

Comment: This seems rather hacky, but is a simple solution. I hoped for an API method, though...

Comment: @janoliver did you come up with a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Set clickable to true on the drawer - it'll consume the touch.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I added `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` because marking the drawer as interactive (clickable or focusable) will make the entire drawer visible to accessibility services like TalkBack.

This is not what you want (usually) - more often, items *inside* the drawer should be accessible to the services.

This attribute is only available on API 16+.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I will try it later, thank you for the answer! And to answer your comment-question: I did not find an elegant solution yet. Your's would be the first. :)

Comment: I just wanted to add a note for anyone that might find it helpful. My `DrawerLayout` contained a `fragment` instead of `FrameLayout` for `@+id/sidebar_container` (or `@+id/navigation_drawer` in my case). You can simply add `android:clickable="true"` to the base Layout of that fragment's xml file instead because `fragment` won't recognize the `clickable` attribute.

Comment: A great solution!